# How many serial ports are on the Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, serial

How many serial ports are on the Pi 3?  There is one on the GPIO pin that goes to `ttyS0`. Is there a separate one for USB? I have read somewhere about `/dev/ttyUSB0`.  Is that a separate serial port?

Can I attach 2 different devices 1 at each ttyS0 and ttyUSB0 and read from them simultanously using python for example.

Place mentioning `ttyUSB0`:
https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-the-raspberry-pi/setting-everything-up

Answer (score 8):

The Pi has 2 serial ports, but only 1 is accessible - the other is connected to Bluetooth. (It is possible to switch ports in Device Tree.)

See [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3 , Pi3B+, PiZeroW](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) for more detail.

You can add additional ports with a USB-serial adapter.

Comment: Conscise answer (+1) but maybe just clarify that USB-serial adaptors are (depending on the driver etc.etc.) the `ttyUSBn` mentioned by the OP in the question?

Answer (score 4):

***Question***

How many serial ports are on the Rpi3

***Answer***

I have been playing with serial communication this couple of days.  I googled  and the found the following tutorial useful.

[Raspberry Pi Serial (UART) Tutorial - Roland Pelayo 2018jun22 17,305 Views](https://www.teachmemicro.com/raspberry-pi-serial-uart-tutorial/)

I extracted what the author says below:

> Technically, the Raspberry Pi has two UARTs: ***PL011 UART*** and mini UART.
>   However, you only have one pair of TXD and RXD pins to work with.
>
> The PL011 UART is the main UART for models without Bluetooth feature
>   and is tied directly to the Linux console output. This means you can
>   send Linux commands from your PC to the Raspberry Pi on this UART.
>
> *On the other hand, the mini UART becomes the Linux console UART for*
>   *models with Bluetooth like the Raspberry Pi 3 and Raspberry Pi Zero W.*
>   For these models, the PL011 UART is tied directly to the Bluetooth
>   module.
>
> Whichever UART is assigned to the Linux console is accessible through
>   ***/dev/serial0***. Each UART can be accessed individually via ***/dev/ttyS0***
>   for the mini UART and ***/dev/ttyAMA0*** for the PL011 UART.
>
> Generally, the PL011 UART is more reliable than the mini UART because
>   the latter has smaller FIFOs, lacks flow control and has its baud
>   rate reliant on the VPU clock speed.

***My experiment results***

I followed Roland Pelayo's instructions and have been doing experiments and found everything works as he suggests.

I used to use four TXS0104 logical level converters to demux one UART channel into 4. I select one one of the four channels by enabling TXS0104 converter I want.  It works smoothly, except you can not use more than one UART channel at the same time.

I also tried the USB to TTL adapters for Rpi3B+ Raspbian version 2019Apr.  I found both PL2302 and CH340 adapters can be detected without first installing drivers.

In other words, Raspbian version 2019apr already have Pl2303 and CH340 drivers preinstalled.

I also tried the CP2102 USB to TTL adapters, but many CP2102 modules are sadly not compatible to Win10 and ESP8266-12.  I have not tried it on Rpi (*see update below*).

[image: rpi3b+ usb ttl driver]

***NXP SC16IS750 I2C/SPI to UART Module Not Recommended for Newbies***

SparkFun once sold a NXP I2C/SPI to UART module.  I thought it too good to be true to be able to have as many UART channels as I wanted.  But then I found the datasheet has some "special features" which are perhaps OK for hackers to deal with, but too hard for newbies to handle. I tried hard for a couple of days before giving up.  SparkFun has now discontinued this module for a reason.

The other modules AdaFruit are recommending are TXS/TXB0108 modules.  I have been using TSX/TSB0104s for demultiplexing UART/I2C/SPI channels and found them OK, if not too greedy to entertain too many channels at the same time.  Actually I found many I2C modules (including MCP23017) when grouped more than two, become unstable and difficult to troubleshoot.  Perhaps I have not learnt all the tricks in fiddling the I2C pull up resistors.  Anyway, trying just one is OK for newbies.

Another thing is that I tested both TSX and TSB versions and found TSB more reliable.  I also noticed that AdaFruit only sells TSB now and no loner TSX.  This are the puzzles I never solved.

[image: TSX0104E]

***Update 2019apr20hkt1628***

I checked out more than 20 very old USB to TTL adaptors which have been collecting dust for over 10 years.  I bought some of them for WinXP and found they no longer working for Win7.  I also bouoght some for Win7, and found them no good for Win10.  Just now I tried all these old guys for my Rpi3B+ Raspian 2019Apr to see if I had any luck.  Surprisingly I found the following:

Bad         = 5 (not sure which driver)
Good HL340  = 5
Good PL2302 = 7

[image: testing usb to ttl adapters]

[image: test usb to ttl]

***References***

[AdaFruit TXB0108 8-channel Bi-directional Logic Level Converter - $8.00](https://www.adafruit.com/product/395)

[TXB0108 Datasheet - TI](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/txb0108.pdf)

[TXS0104E Datasheet - TI](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0104e.pdf)

[Amazon SC16IS750 I2C/SPI to UART Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0756XDNRS)

[SparkFun SC16IS750 I2C/SPI-to-UART Module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9981)

[SC16IS750 I2C/SPI to UART Datasheet - NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf?)

[The 6 Best Arduino GPS Modules - Josh Darling 2019jan](https://wiki.ezvid.com/best-arduino-gps-modules)