# Is it possible to change Rx pin as GPIO15 is damaged?

Tags: gpio

I rather stupidly connected 5 V logic directly (without using a level shifter) to Rx, GPIO 15 (pin 10), of my RPi 2B and now it appears to have stopped functioning.

[image: GPIO for RPi 2B]

Could I configure another pin as Rx? Be that via a config file, or setting, or kernel recompile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are alternative usable pins on the compute module.  There are no alternative hardware pins on the other Pis.

I have bit banged serial using my pigpio library.  Anything under 19k2 baud appears rock solid.  Anything faster and you would need error checking.

Bit banging the input side is trivial.

```
sudo pigpiod # start the pigpio daemon

pigs slro 23 19200 8 # open GPIO 23 for 8-bit bytes at 19k2 baud

pigs slr 23 200 # read up to 200 bytes from GPIO 23
```

The output side is a bit more complicated and uses pigpio waves.

Answer (score 1):

***Question***

> connected 5 V logic directly to Rx now it appears to have stopped
>   functioning.
>
> Could I configure another pin as Rx? Be that via a config file, or
>   setting, or kernel recompile?

***Answer***

You can use USB UART/TTL cables.  Then you can have as many UARTs as you have USB/TTL cables.

I have read others experimenting with software serial.  But so far all I have read concludes that the reliability is poor, at best 10% error rate at 9600 8N1.

***References***

[How many [USB] serial ports are on Pi3? - answered Apr 19 by tlfong01](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/how-many-serial-ports-are-on-the-pi-3/96698#96698)

/ to continue, ...

Comment: You deleted something about the "overlay... Stretch...", which seemed quite interesting, but I didn't get time to read it properly

Comment: @Greenonline - Never mind.  All I have read so far says software Rpi UART is not reliable, at 10% error rate even at 96008N1.  So I hesitated to suggest others to try, especially newbies who happen to read my answer.  BTW, this reminds me of the good old days with Arduino's software UARTs.