# Waveshare SIM7600E-H no wwan0 interface when connected to Raspberry Pi 4 model B

Tags: pi-4, raspbian-buster, modules, hat

I have connected the new Raspberry Pi 4 model b with the waveshare SIM7600E-H 4G HAT.
The os is Raspbian Buster Lite.
The configuration I use is the following:
[image]
1) The jumpers are placed in the middle position.
2) The shield connected onto the RPi gpio.
3) There is also a connection between the pi and the waveshare "USB" port (not "USB to UART")
4) raspi-config > Interfacing Options > Serial =
Login shell over serial = NO
Serial port hardware enabled = YES
5) /boot/config.txt has enable_uart=1

So far I have managed to give AT commnads succesfully, and even have access on the internet via ppp0 as it shown in the waveshare wiki page: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/SIM868_P%20...%20Networking

However I haven't managed to find a way to access 4g network via wwan0.
I assume that this is related with the fact that in the /dev/ folder there are no ttyUSB serial ports.

Following info I found here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=224355

I gave the command:

```
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-set-operating-mode='online'
```

and got:

```
error: couldn't create QmiDevice: Couldn't query file info: Error when getting information for file “/dev/cdc-wdm0”: No such file or directory
```

since no /dev/cdc-wdm0 device exist.

I also tried to compile gobiserial from SIM7X00-Driver.7z. I updated the raspberrypi-kernel-headers but when I tried to compile the driver I got the following error:

```
GobiSerial.c:55:10: fatal error: linux/usb-wwan.h: No such file or directory
```

Has anyone any idea why no ttyUSB exist and how can wwan0 be configured

Comment: Try $ ls /dev/ttyUSB*.  For my two opened USB to serial ports on Rpi4B buster release 2019sep26, I got the following: /dev/ttyUSB0  /dev/ttyUSB1. Remember to always use terminal mode raspbi-config (or GUI Desktop equivalent) to (1)  Enable serial port, (2) DISABLE serial console, whether you are using Rpi on board UART or not.

Comment: @tlfong01 The result of the command is cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*.': No such file or directory. And as I have mentioned above I have already done Login shell over serial = NO Serial port hardware enabled = YES via raspbi-config

Comment: (1) I thought you wrongly searched /etc/dev/ttyUSB* instead of /dev/ttyUSB*, so I remind you that.  (2)  My answer is only limited to Rpi UART or USB/UART.  Now a question: I usually python import serial to setup the USB serial ports.  Do you use terminal commands or also python to setup USB serial ports?  I am trying to point out that Rpi built in serial ports will setup "automatically", but for USB/UART, some cables's driver is not recognized, so you need to install drivers.  I remember something like CH340, PL2xxx are OK.  But I am not very sure.  Perhaps I can check tomorrow. Bye.

Comment: I mean I read your comment "I assume that this is related with the fact that in the /etc/dev/ folder there are no ttyUSB serial ports.“. So I thought you searched the wrong folder.  The correct folder should be just /dev/*.*. My apologies if my folder knowledge is wrong.

Comment: @tlfong01 Hi again and thanks for your answers. It's the first time I'm dealing with a raspberry pi so I haven't used neither terminal commands  nor python to set up USB serial ports. If you have any recommendations on which to use they are more than welcome.

Comment: Hi @dk13, The first part of my answer to the following question mentions a newbie friendly tutorial, followed by how I tested the USB/TTL cables, and which drivers are good for Rpi. Good luck and cheers. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/how-many-serial-ports-are-on-the-pi-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to press the pwrkey for around 3 seconds. Then wait for the Net LED to turn on (it can take up to around 15s). If there is a network, it should start slowly blinking after another 3-10 Seconds. Then try to run the command again.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone has also issues. The link to the raspberry pi forum helped me.
Following steps are working for me.

```
#install the packages
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libqmi-utils udhcpc
ifconfig wwan0 down
# Enable OS Raw IP Mode setting (not persistent) 
echo Y > /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw_ip
ifconfig wwan0 up
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-set-operating-mode='online'
#change apn value according to the service provider information (also maybe username and password are needed)
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --device-open-net="net-raw-ip|net-no-qos-header" --wds-start-network="apn='internet',ip-type=4" --client-no-release-cid 
udhcpc -i wwan0
```

Answer (score 2):

If ModemManager is running (which is is in recent versions of Ubuntu Desktop), it can block qmcli from working.

You can check if its running

```
$ ps ax | grep -i modem
832 ?        Ssl    0:01 /usr/sbin/ModemManager
```

And if so you can stop it with

```
sudo systemctl unmask ModemManager.service # may need this
sudo systemctl disable ModemManager.service
```

Comment: This seems to have also been the case on my Raspberry Pi running Pi OS lite 64-bit based on Debian 11. Had to just run `sudo systemctl stop ModemManager` and then I could run `qmicli` commands.