# How to configure the RaspberryPi-B1 RFID reader by Eccel?

Tags: python, serial, rfid

I am trying to configure the B1 RFID hat on my raspberry pi since it is a cleaner solution than using a USB RFID reader. However I have ran into some issues.

Firstly, [the documentation supplied by Eccel](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/radio-frequency-development-kits/1368714?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_UK_EN_Semiconductors-_-Semiconductor_Development_Kits%7CRadio_Frequency_Development_Kits-_-PRODUCT_GROUP&matchtype=&aud-827186183926:pla-566139804874&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1YC7npvE5gIVGLLtCh1uVAo3EAQYAiABEgJBMPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) is very minimal and offers no library or install guide specific to a Raspberry Pi. It only offers information on a previous model not suited to a pi.

I have tried using some data and know-how, I have tried to use the UART serial to read back data from an RFID card, however it returns nothing. Here is the code I am using:

```
import time, serial

port = serial.Serial("/dev/serial0", baudrate=9600, timeout=3.0)

while True:
    print(port.read(100)) #<-- I assume here the argument is bit count??
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

This code does not return any errors, it just doesn't print any response when a card is presented.

If anyone has experience with this particular product and can offer an insight it will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why guess? Read the documentation. https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read read(size=1) Parameters: size – Number of bytes to read. Returns: Bytes read from the port. Return type: bytes Read size bytes from the serial port. If a timeout is set it may return less characters as requested. With no timeout it will block until the requested number of bytes is read.

Comment: This is not an answer, it only confirms what I already thought. This does not contribute to solving my problem at all. This should have been a comment at the very most

Comment: Actually it would seem to contradict what you already thought: *"I assume here the argument is bit count??"* -- nope, docs say **bytes**.

Comment: I skimmed your RFID thing and wow! I have never seen such a deluxe RFID/NFC reader with a Swiss army knife with too many blades (see Fig 1.1 of user manual), no wonder it costs you £30+. Newbie starting suggestion: (1) Do not connect it to Rpi yet.  Try to see if you can use Win10 RealTerm to say Hello (eg. "AT" command) talk to it using USB/UART 9k6bd8n1. If successful, then use Rpi python built in UART (TxD/RxD), or USB to TTL UART.

Comment: The module is very standard interface, so I guess it should be easy to mess around. Reference: (1) My comments of this UART projector Q&A - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105405/rpi-zero-and-projectors-usb-rs232-serial-cable-interface-connection-problem. (2) RaspberryPi-B1 - Product Details and Specifications- RS 2017apr24
https://docs.rs-online.com/9b30/0900766b815c553a.pdf

(3) RaspberryPi-B1 User Manual V1.2 (UART COM port) - Eccel
https://docs.rs-online.com/e911/0900766b815c553b.pdf

Comment: (4) Eccel Technology Ltd Hat RFID/NFC Raspberry Pi HAT for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B - RaspberryPi-B1 (000367) Eccel Tech £33
https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/radio-frequency-development-kits/1368714?cm_mmc=UK-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_UK_EN_Semiconductors-_-Semiconductor_Development_Kits%7CRadio_Frequency_Development_Kits-_-PRODUCT_GROUP&matchtype=&aud-827186183926:pla-566139804874&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI1YC7npvE5gIVGLLtCh1uVAo3EAQYAiABEgJBMPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: I don't quite agree with you saying that your chosen rfid module is a "cleaner solution", for the following reasons: (1) HAT is not very standard, and often causes trouble, especially when swithing raspbian versions (stretech to buster, eg). (2) To learn or troubleshooting, I always recommend to use the Occam's razor stratigy - "Make it as simple as possible, but not simpler" (sort of KISS). For a rfid newbie like me, I think yours is the most mucky and expensive solution.

Comment: (Don't get me wrong - I am a hugh fan of RS (not so of E14) for decades, they do sell fanstic industrial grade goodies, but this time what you need is a really cheap toy to learn and fry). Me newbies would start with really cheap modules from really cheap shops like Alibaba/TaoBao/AliExpress (never mind them ofen selling fake stuff) the following: https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-rfid-module.html.

Comment: I would suggest to try the newer red module (about US$4, but newer), with key rings.  I do have those red anbd blue toys in hand. If you wold like to start with those cheap toys, I am happy to share with you my play experience using Rpi4B Thonny python 3.7.3. Happy rfiding.  Cheers.