# Connecting a USB Device by GND, VCC, RX, and TX

Tags: usb, uart, electronics, troubleshooting

I have a few basic devices that utilize a mini USB port. Rather than plugging them into a USB hub, is it possible to connect them and have them recognized by a Raspberry Pi through the four GND, VCC, RX, and TX wires?
I've enabled UART successfully and tried plugged in Red => 3.3v, Black => GND, Green => RX, White => TX, but I cannot get my device to show up on the Pi (I've also tried switching the White and Green wires just in case I got them mixed up).

The program I'd like to utilize the devices with does search for a `/dev/ttyS*` device and the UART is at `/dev/ttyAMA0`, so I tried linking `/dev/ttyAMA0` to `/dev/ttyS1` in hopes that the program will pick the device up, but it doesn't work. Is there is a way to get something like this working?

[image: wire]

Comment: Ah, what you should use is an "USB to UART/Serial/TTL" cable.  See my answer to the following question for more details: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/how-many-serial-ports-are-on-the-pi-3. Cheers.

Comment: USB doesn't have TX and RX lines, it has D+ and D-.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

The USB protocol is different to the simple serial protocol used by a UART.