# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B FTDI USB to Serial converter driver problem

Tags: raspbian, usb, serial, uart

I've been suffering to introduce my USB to Serial (RS232) FTDI converter on Raspbian 10 on my Raspberry pi 3 Model B.

- In Windows 10 it works without installing an additional driver.
  FTDI drivers available at https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm and I found related ARM builds and compiled examples successfully.
- There is no pre-installed conflicting ftdi_sio or usbserail library available as a module. lsmod doesn't list and when I try to rmmode it says module is not installed.
- in examples/EEPROM/read/ sudo ./read can't find device. gtkterm doesn't recognize it either.
- According to FTDI developer spec under read/main.c I manually set VID and PID values and printed in the console. Still it's not detecting my converter.

P.S. I'm doing FT_SetVIDPID(0x0403,0x6001) before FT_open in main.c, you can see it from the console output as well.
In the FTDI site it's mentioned 3 starred *** versions of drivers support raspberry pi and this vendor and PID must be covered by default.

You can find installation details [here](https://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/ReadMe-linux.txt).

Any recommendation ?

[image]

But unfortunately in linux all my attempts failed.

[image]