# Waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNSS Hat SIM868 '+CGPSSTATUS: Location Not Fix'

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Currently, I'm trying to receive a GPS location using the Waveshare GSM/GPRS/GNS Hat for the raspberry pi. After connecting the module and connecting to it using serial, I use the `AT+CGNSPWR=1` command to turn on GNS. After leaving it for multiple minutes, the `AT+CGNSINF` command only returns:
`+CGNSINF: 1,0,19800106004706.000,,,,0.00,0.0,0,,,,,,0,0,,,,,`

and the `AT+CGPSSTATUS?` command returns `+CGPSSTATUS: Location Not Fix`

Any idea why it's not getting a location and what could be done to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Troubleshooting suggestion: (1) Perhaps you should place the GPS receiver in an open space.

Comment: Gave it a try, but even on my balcony with a unobstructed view of the sky it has the same results.

Comment: Is your antenna with a long cable? This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/130705/pico-pi-rtc-interrupt/140932#140932. Or get a cheapy Neo 6/7/8M and use ublox ucentre to do the setup and testing.

Comment: I once tried SIM7600 and found the GPS part disappointing: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113992/rpi3b-python-controlling-multiple-sim800-sim900-sim7600-modules/114038#114038. That is whay I suggest to try Neo xM to compare and contrast.

Comment: @tlfong01 I'm using the antenna which came with the module, which has a long cable. Where can i find a module using the Neo xM for the raspberry pi?

Comment: For newbies, I would recommend basic standard basic versions Neo-6M from AliEx or Amazon. You don't need the new fancy version V2 with EEPROM which might be tricky for newbies to handle.